# How do I set the Name Box using an excel VBA macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, rename

I'm building a model that takes the results from the first sheet and inputs them into the next sheet.  Effectively creating an application that runs in series.  I have defined the values in the first sheet by the Name Box so that I can call upon these values and use them in formulas with ease.

The next step is the create the second worksheet so that the cells I need to use in formulas can be named (in the namebox) with the same names as in sheet 1, but with the addition on some suffix (e.g. 1, or A).

This way sheet 1 will have cells with names such as SA, Vol, Q, etc. and sheet 2 will have cells with names such as SA1, Vol1, Q1, etc.

The parameter names exist in adjacent cells.  For examples, I want to name cells in column C, using their adjacent value/word in column B.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub CreatName()
  Dim cel As Range
  Dim moretext As Variant

  moretext = InputBox("Enter text to add at end of name box: ")

  For Each cel In Worksheets("Model").Range("C:C").Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(cel.Value) Then
      cel.Name = cel.Offset(0, -1).Value & moretext
      MsgBox (cel.Name.Value)
    End If
  Next cel
End Sub
```

I can't seem to get it to work.  The cel.name spits out the cell location (e.g. `="Model"$C$25`), and I can't get the suffix to add onto the name.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value use something like this:

```
MsgBox (cel.Name.RefersToRange.Value)
```

---

To add a name do this:

```
cName = cel.Offset(0, -1).Value & moretext

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=cName, RefersToR1C1:=cell
```